# Linq-to-SQL select many columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq-to-SQL and I just started to learn some of the basics. I have problem with select command many columns in many tables. I give songs which selected into session (contain songid) and display songname, artistname, genrename in datagrid.

But it's not working.

```
ArrayList SelectedSongs = (ArrayList)Session["SelectedSongs"];

string songIds = "";

foreach (int id in SelectedSongs)
            songIds += id + ", ";

var query = from s in sa.Songs
            from ar in sa.Artists
            from g in sa.Genres
            where s.SongID in (songIds)
            select new { s.SongID, s.SongName, ar.ArtistName, g.GenreName };

dgSongs.DataSource = query;
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Error message: Invalid expression term 'in'

Comment: It looks like you are missing some JOINs. A good resource I've found is [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688085](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688085) There you will find a few options under JOIN

Comment: SongAlbumDBDataContext sa = new SongAlbumDBDataContext(connStr);

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is not correct Linq:

```
where s.SongID in (songIds)
```

The Linq equivalent of SQL's `WHERE IN` is to use `Contains()`. You have to turn the statement around and start with the list:

```
where songIds.Contains(s.SongID)
```

When using Linq-to-SQL you should always use *navigation properties* instead of explicit joins. If you have proper foreign keys between your tables those properties will be automatically created. With navigation properties and `songIDs` changed into an `int[]` your query should be something like this:

```
int[] songIDs = ((ArrayList)Session["SelectedSongs"]).OfType<int>().ToArray();

var query = from s in sa.Songs
            where songIDs.Contains(s.SongID)
            select new 
            { 
              s.SongID, 
              s.SongName, 
              s.Artist.ArtistName, 
              s.Genre.GenreName 
            };
```

Comment: can't implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Genric.List<int>' to int[]

Comment: If this answer is the one that solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to Join multiple tables. I would recommend to take a look at the Join section [of this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688085). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want songIds to be an int[] instead of a csv of ids.